# Javascript PayPal button SDK : How to get the negative test scenarios?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Not able to get the paypal negative test scenarios. Tried adding the mock headers to the onApprove callback.

I want to test funding failures,the last part https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/handle-funding-failures/

I think I add the mock header in the right place but is doing nothing it keeps saying Transaction completed . Whats the proper way to put it? Paypal says:

```
paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/create/', {
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(orderData) {
                return orderData.id;
            });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'PayPal-Mock-Response': '{"mock_application_codes" : "INSTRUMENT_DECLINED" }'
                },
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(orderData) {
                var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];
                console.log('paypal error errorDetail', orderData)

                if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                    return actions.restart();
                }

                if (errorDetail) {
                    var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
                    if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
                    if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
                    return alert(msg); 
                }

                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');
            });
        }

    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

the above is my code. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The headers are not to be added when the JS code fetches from routes on your server (`'/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/` in your example).

The headers are to be added *inside* those routes, in the code on your server, when it calls the v2/checkout/orders API to capture the order.